# WP WooCoommerce integration with Braintree leads to Failed to Create Customer error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, braintree

I have a WordPress Site with WooCommerce installed, and I added a Braintree Payments extension to it today.

The instructions to set this up are very simple: activate the extension and its license, ensure that your Braintree account is in Development mode, add your Merchant Account Number, public key, private key, and client-side encryption key. Should work, right?

Well, upon testing, I get this error for every attempt:

An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment.

Failed to create customer

81706 : CVV is required., 81713 : Expiration year is invalid., 81712 : Expiration month is invalid., 81714 : Credit card number is required., 81725 : Credit card must include number, paymentMethodNonce, or venmoSdkPaymentMethodCode.

All of these inputs (CC Number, Expiration date, and CCV) were entered on submitting the form.

I have gone back through all my keys/account number to check that there was no whitespace included, I've tested multiple cards, I have checked all my settings in WooCommerce, and I have the updated versions of WordPress and all plugins. WTF is going on?!?!!

Thank you for any help you can give!

Caitlin

Answer (score 2):

The type of error you are receiving is often associated with an incorrect Client-side encryption key. What's likely happening is the data (CC #, CVV, Exprations date) is encrypted with an incorrect key, and when Braintree attempts to decrypt it, the data is giberish, causing them to return validation errors.

I work at Braintree. Feel free to e-mail us at solutions@braintereepayments.com with screenshots of your settings, and we'd be happy to look in our logs to see if it matches what's being passed by the WooCommerce extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may try another **free** plugin that I subjectively think is better integrated with WordPress and WooCommerce. It is called [Woo Braintree Payment](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-mynix-braintree/) and obviously you can find it and use it for free from WordPress.org (install it from your WordPress website, the Plugin menu).

Please note that I am the author of this plugin so, as I've said before, this is a subjective opinion/recommendation.